# What is the default encoding when saving a text file

Tags: c#, encoding

When saving a text file client gets 'Â' character infront of every currency sign.

I tried the following but still getting strange characters

```
using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(path, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    sr.Write(text);
}
using (StreamWriter sr = File.CreateText(path))
{
    sr.Write(text);
}
```

any suggestions on how to save a file without any encoding?

Comment: You can't save a file without any encoding, the default encoding depends on the local system (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx). What kind of currency symbols are you talking about? only $ or are there others?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that the client is using the wrong encoding.  You should find out what encoding they are expecting / can handle successfully and use that.  It may be helpful to provide a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: How are you opening this file? It seems more likely that the flaw is there than here. Using anything other that UTF-8 should be strongly discouraged if at all possible. Alas, TARDISs don't exist or we could sort it out for once and for all ;)

Comment: I am not opening this file client is.I am saving this file

Comment: @Justm they seem they want Ansi

Comment: @user231465 ansi is not a single thing. Basically, you are talking about a code-page. If you want to save a file in *their* default code-page, **ask them** what their code-page is (or write a tool to do it).

Comment: I should also emphasise: UTF8 would be a far better way to encode this data!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> any suggestions on how to save a file without any encoding?

That question is meaningless; the "encoding" is the process of translating string characters to bytes to store/transfer (for example on disk). Any text content has to have *an* encoding. If you have saved it as UTF8, then the person reading it must also be reading it *as* UTF8. You *could* try including a BOM:

```
... new StreamWriter(path, false, new UTF8Encoding(true))
```

Alternatively, find out what encoding/code-page YOUR MACHINE is configured to use by default, and use that (it is `Encoding.Default`); for example:

```
... new StreamWriter(path, false, Encoding.Default)
```

If your user indicates that they need it in code-page 874 (aka "Thai"), then you would use:

```
... new StreamWriter(path, false, Encoding.GetEncoding(874))
```

Comment: @MarcGravell .Thanks for your reply.When client saves it to Ansi it does not get problem .

Comment: @user231465 there is no single ansi. Either you mean ascii (7-bit only), or you mean **some specific codepage**, and you need to know which code-page it *is*. The current system-default code-page is, already noted, `Encoding.Default`. However, note that in a server/client scernaio it is likely that the server's default code-page and the client's default code-page are different.

Comment: @user231465 if the user indicates that they are using, for example, code-page 874 ("Thai"), then you would use (as the final parameter) `Encoding.GetEncoding(874)`

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for your suggestion all sorted .Agreed with client and we both use same encoding now

Comment: How to find out? How to change? Thats the real question I guess isnt it?

Answer (score 8):

StreamWriter with a stream as input would default to [UTF-8 according to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9.aspx).

> This constructor creates a StreamWriter with UTF-8 encoding without a Byte-Order Mark (BOM), so its GetPreamble method returns an empty byte array.

Comment: this seems to be the only answer that actually answers the question

Comment: @Andy this seems to be the only answer that answers the question *in the title*. The OP asks something different in the body of the question.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on your computer's local settings. If you want to be sure everything is saved as you intended, you should specify the encoding yourself.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx

Comment: The default encoding is the "encoding for the operating system's current ANSI code page."